# Tsconfig preserveSymlink breaks express types

Tags: typescript, express, npm, package.json, pnpm

I am in a peculiar situation, without `"preserveSymlinks": true` in my `tsconfig.json`. I get the following errors, [as seen in this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42873)

```
The inferred type of "X" cannot be named without a reference to "Y". This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
```

Exact error

```
src/api/controllers/validators.ts(5,14): error TS2742: The inferred type of 'commonSchema' cannot be named without a reference to '.pnpm/joi@17.6.2/node_modules/joi'. This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
```

So as the issue stated I added `"preserveSymlinks": true` and this indeed did fix the issue, but now this has broken the types for `express`. I made a [reproducable repo](https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/monorepo-issue), I use pnpm and if you navigate to `apps/backend/src` you can see that the types for express are broken, if you remove the `"preserveSymlinks": true` from the `tsconfig.json` it works. But I need the `preserveSymlinks` setting for the previous error which breaks the `express` types

Comment: Have you tried the other workaround from linked github issue of .npmrc file with auto-install-peers=true & node-linker=hoisted?

Comment: @Michael yeah I did, I tried every solution I came across. Eventually just switched to Yarn as it provided similar benefits and it integrated in my setup much easier.